# How to close a Stream created inside a Bloc in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Stream` to validate text fields on `home_page`. I am using `Stream` in `Bloc`. After closing the page, I need to close these `Streams`. Tell me if I close them correctly, is it possible to close `Streams` like this? Or do I need to close streams in another way?

**bloc**

```
class ValidationCubit extends Cubit<ValidationState> {
  ValidationCubit() : super(ValidationInitial());

  final StreamController<String?> _numCarController =
      StreamController<String?>.broadcast();
  final StreamController<String?> _yearController =
      StreamController<String?>.broadcast();
  final StreamController<bool> _buttonController =
      StreamController<bool>.broadcast()..add(false);

  Stream<String?> get numberStream => _numberController.stream;
  Stream<String?> get yearStream => _yearController.stream;
  Stream<bool> get buttonStream => _buttonController.stream;

  bool isNumber = false;
  bool isYear = false;

  void checkNumber(String number) {
    if (number.isEmpty) {
      isNumber = false;
      _numberCarController.add('Empty');
    } else {
      isNumber = true;
      _numberCarController.add(null);
    }
  }

  void checkYear(String year) {
    if (year.isEmpty) {
      isYear = false;
      _yearCarController.add('Empty');
    } else {
      isYear = true;
      _yearController.add(null);
    }
  }

  void checkButton() {
    if (isNumber && isYear) {
      _buttonController.add(true);
    } else {
      _buttonController.add(false);
    }
  }

  void closeStreams() {
    _numberController.close();
    _yearController.close();
    _buttonController.close();
  }
}
```

**home_page**

```
ValidationCubit? validationCubit;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    validationCubit?.closeStreams();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    validationCubit = BlocProvider.of<ValidationCubit>(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
....
```

Comment: Why does your Cubit need manually handled Streams? Isn't the whole point of this BLoC library to do that *for you*? Shouldn't you be emitting states instead of streaming things yourself?

Comment: I did it just to separate the logic, I understand that Bloc is not necessary for this, it is enough to make a separate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the streams are made and handled inside the Cubit, you should definitely handle them inside of it, so if the cubit is opened the streams should be too, and the same if the cubit is closed.

you can override the `close()` method which exists for `Cubit`/`Bloc` for closing and free resources when the bloc is done and it is closed, so the streams will be always related to the cubit open/close state, not an external factor such as the widget state.

```
class ValidationCubit extends Cubit<ValidationState> {
  //...

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
   closeStreams();
   return super.close();
  }
 }
```

then what you should now be closing externally, is the cubit itself:

```
@override
 void dispose() {
  validationCubit?.close();
 }
```

by this, you can make sure that if the cubit is on, the streams are open and can be used when the dispose() will be called (when the widget is out the widget is killed) the whole cubit will close(), which will close internally the streams as well.

Comment: Do I need didChangeDependencies? This is where i initialize validationCubit

Comment: you're more likely need to initialize it in the initState()

Comment: DidChangeDependencies is also initialized, so I think there is no difference